# ShowMessageAsync above user control

Tags: .net, wpf, material-design, mahapps.metro

I have several userControls on top of each other like this:

[image: 1]]

They're spawned like this:

```
await System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async () =>
        {
            var view = new ListarAlertas(id);
            await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog");
         }));

var view = new CerrarAlerta()
        {
            DataContext = new CerrarAlertaViewModel(Item.Id)
        };
        var result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "ListarAlertasHost");
```

And if I show an error like this in CerrarAlertaViewModel

```
MetroWindow metroWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow;
MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme = MetroDialogColorScheme.Inverted;
metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Error", "Debe elegir un tipo de incidente.");
```

I get this
[image]

And I want the error message to appear above every userControl I made.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's a demo showing my problem.  The error message should appear above all dialogs.

https://github.com/Vallo/DemoErrorWpf

Comment: Can you make a sample so that we can reproduce the issue? or show some code? Also perhaps you should tag this question with **mahapps.metro** since you are using this library and perhaps it is related with your issue

Comment: Here's a working demo sample. The error should appear above the userDialog.

https://github.com/Vallo/DemoErrorWpf